# alternative way to DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

i have sql statement like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT results_sp_08.material_number FROM results_sp_08
        INNER JOIN courses ON results_sp_08.material_number = courses.material_number
        INNER JOIN users ON results_sp_08.id = users.id
        AND results_sp_08.doctor = 'xx260'
```

i need alternative way to DISTINCT in to use it in MySQL version: 4.1.22 ?

is there another way or trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Joel, your best bet is to add the GROUP BY clause. In your case

```
GROUP BY results_sp_08.material_number
```

Answer (score 4):

`DISTINCT` is functionally equivalent to `GROUP BY <all the columns in your select list>`

Comment: Had to downvote because your description is not clear. Distinct can be used on a single column in a Selection.

Comment: @d03boy: No, DISTINCT applies to all columns in the select-list.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a double-join strategy on these:

```
JOIN tablex AS x1 ON whatever  
LEFT JOIN tablex AS x2 ON whatever  
    AND x2.pkid < x1.pkid AND x2.somefield IS NULL
```

which guarantees I get at most 1 record on all my joins.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully eliminated DISTINCT by adding more clauses to my WHERE in the past. You need to look at what fields in your JOINs are causing multiple rows to come back. A subquery may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the tables structure it is hard to tell.
You need to say in words what you are trying to do.

Assuming that the result_sp_08 contains only unique "material_number"s, and
you are trying to get all the unique material_number that had at least one row in courses and users tables:

```
SELECT results\_sp\_08.material\_number
FROM results\_sp\_08
WHERE results\_sp\_08.doctor = 'xx260' and
EXISTS(select * from courses
    where results\_sp\_08.material\_number = courses.material\_number) and
EXISTS(select * from users
    where results\_sp\_08.id = users.id)
```

See the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Exists doesn't exist in his MySQL version.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT results_sp_08.material_number FROM results_sp_08
       INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
       results_sp_08.material_number = c.material_number
       INNER JOIN users AS u ON results_sp_08.id = u.id
       AND results_sp_08.doctor = 'xx260'
GROUP BY results_sp_08.material_number.
```

Added group by clause and removed distinct. And one of the best practices: Always use aliases when using JOIN.